# Geoserver Error: No Such Feature Type in WFS-T

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wfs-t

I was able to successfully create a Wfs_T app using the tutorial from https://medium.com/@goldrydigital/wfs-t-with-openlayers-3-16-6fb6a820ac58. I then decided to use this code to edit a file I'd made by creating a shapefile in QGIS, uploading into PostGIS, and then bringing it into GeoServer. To do this, all I did was change the code from

```
$.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/his_workspace/ows?', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typename: 'his_layer_name',
                srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
            }
            })
var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
            featureNS: 'his_workspace',
            featureType: 'his_layer_name',
            srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
            });
```

to

```
$.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/my_workspace/ows?', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typename: 'my_layer_name',
                srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
            }
            })
var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
            featureNS: 'my_workspace',
            featureType: 'my_layer_name',
            srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
            });
```

And I also changed

```
 $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/his_workspace/ows', {
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'xml',
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'text/xml',
    data: payload
}).done(function() {
    sourceWFS.clear();
});
```

to

```
 $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/my_workspace/ows', {
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'xml',
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'text/xml',
    data: payload
}).done(function() {
    sourceWFS.clear();
});
```

And Geoserver sends me the message:

org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: No such feature type my_workspace:my_layer_name.

My describe feature type result is this:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:my_workspace="my_workspace" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="www.my_workspace.com">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="my_layer_nameType">
    <xsd: complexContent>
      <xsd: extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="id" nillable="false" type="xsd:long"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="geom" nillable="true" type="gml:PointPropertyType"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd: extension>
    </xsd: complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="my_layer_name" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="my_workspace:my_layer_nameType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

My workspace, data store, and namespace all have the same name. The constraints and other settings that the tutorial mentions seem to be the same for my file. I tried changing the namespace to a URI and I still get the error message. I do wonder if it's because the geometry is in a point(geometry) type while in the tutorial it's simply in a geometry type.

Edit: here is the XML: `Raw XML request: <Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"><Insert><my_layer_name xmlns="my_workspace"><geometry><Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:3857"><pos srsDimension="2">-724011.5319171895 7284143.047464156</pos></Point></geometry></my_layer_name></Insert></Transaction>`

Does anyone know why this isn't going through?

Comment: please show use the exact code and xml sent to the server with obfuscation - turn the GeoServer logging up to geoserver-dev and include the relevant part of the log file

Comment: Okay, so just to be sure I understand you, I went to Global Settings in GeoServer and I changed the logging profile to "Geoserver_Developer_Logging.properties. I've added the XML as well.

Answer (score 3):

(Did you allow WFS-t on the geoserver side at first?)

Can you try set type name parameter with workspace of wfs feature.

```
$.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/my_workspace/ows?', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typename: 'workspace_name:layer_name',
                srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
            }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer but here it comes, you can change feature layers name and geometry column like this before you post to WFS:

```
//Change feature name
const find_feature = `feature:${layerName}`;
const re_feature = new RegExp(find_feature, "g");

//Change feature geometry column
const find_geometry = `<Property><Name>geometry</Name>`;
const re_geometry = new RegExp(find_geometry, "g");

const payload = xs.serializeToString(formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, f, null, formatGML))
 .replace(re_feature, `Bugra:${layerName}`)
 .replace(re_geometry, `<Property><Name>${layerGeometryColumn}</Name>`);
```